# Tab in Firefox shows improper charset while loading

Tags: firefox, character-encoding, tabs

While loading the content, Firefox (in Ubuntu, Windows, MacOs) shows for a second improper charset (namely Czech letters). When the content is loaded, it shows a proper charset.
Safari, Explorer, Opera shows tab when loading correctly.

Html head is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<title><?=$lang_header_dict;?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?=$lang_head_description?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?=$lang_head_content?>">
<meta name="author" content="<?=$lang_head_author?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="hvalur" href="style.css">   
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setfocus() {
document.form1.search_string.focus();
}
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=400,width=800, scrollbars=yes');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
```

Title contains Czech national characaters.

Comment: testcase link? I'm guessing you don't specify the charset in the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the meta line before the title line, your page's charset may be overridden by Apache's default charset. This is by design.

To solve this issue, add the following to your config file:

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
```

See: http://padawan.info/en/2004/07/debugging-chars.html

Answer (score 0):

Placing meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

before

`<title><?=$lang_header_dict;?></title>`

shows correct charset and national characters.